# iOS 11.0.1 crash in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios11, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have several UIViews in my ViewController that are initially hidden. They become unhidden once I get a successful response from Firebase. These initially hidden views have constraints (from Storyboard) that I am modifying in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` based on device size.

Up until iOS 11.0, this worked perfect. Perfect = The views remained hidden. Once Firebase returned a value, the views became unhidden and were the correct size based on the constraints I have set in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

From iOS 11.0.1 and up, I'm now crashing in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is the code in my `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` that's causing the crash in *only* iOS 11.0.1 and up.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 736 { // iPhone 8+
        welcomeViewWidthConstant.constant = 160.0
        welcomeViewHeightConstant.constant = 160.0
    }
}
```

`welcomeViewWidthConstant` and `welcomeViewHeightConstant` are the height and width constraints for the view that is not visible until the Firebase response.

And again, the above was working perfect in iOS 11.0

**How can I set the constraints (based on device size) in iOS 11.0.1 and above?**

Comment: can you try the current code on iOS 10.x. You might be searching the solution in wrong direction.

Comment: I would change the NSLayoutConstraints to optionals and unwrap them in the function... Also you should call super.viewDidLayoutSubviews...

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error? Clearly some implicitly unwrapped variable is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy - you're correct! I didn't realize that the constraints connections were disconnected in storyboard. So my code to update the constraint constants was referencing a nil variable.

Comment: By the way, don’t forget to call `super` when you override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the heads up! super is added :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that welcomeViewWidthConstant is an outlet that you declared with a ! (implicitly unwrapped).

If so, I would look at the stack trace that this is being called in -- is it possible the view is not loaded?

Add

```
guard let self.isViewLoaded else { return }
```

to the top of the function

But, I also think it's weird that you would change a constraint in didLayout.  I would expect that you would call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on the return from Firebase (probably moving to main queue) and then override `updateConstraints` to do the update.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, thank you for lending a hand! I actually found the culprit... The connection to the constraint was disconnected within the storyboard. So the @IBOutlet for welcomeViewWidthConstant and welcomeViewHeightConstant was in fact nil. What was throwing me off was my device isn't an iPhone 8+ size, so it slipped through the cracks.

Comment: :) . Thats what.